# Extend security configuration from Symfony Bundle

Tags: symfony, security, bundle

How to extend security configuration from Symfony Bundle?

I have my basic `config/packages/security.yaml` file and another one in a bundle `src/CustomBundle/Resources/config/security.yaml` that adds new encoders, providers, firewalls and paths in access_control. I am trying to load it inside bundle extension class, but I get an error that security extension was not found

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "security"

```
class CustomExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
        $loader->load('security.yml');
    }
}
```

Using Symfony 4.4

Comment: It's easy to confuse configuring services with configuring bundles.  The load method is for configuring services only.  It's been awhile since I used this but I think you need to use the [prepend functionality](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html).  Which can be equally confusing I might add.  You also try using the import capability.

Comment: Just as a follow up, I added `imports:
    - { resource: '@MyBundle/Resources/config/security.yaml' } ` to config/packages/security.yaml.  Which initially seemed to work but then complained when I tried to add another firewall.  Symfony really seems to want security configuration in one file.  You can experiment more but you might just have to use one file or maybe try getting fancy with compiler passes and whatnot.  Or perhaps use prepend.  Let us know if you get something working.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for the tip, unfortunately there is another error "You are not allowed to define new elements for path "security.firewalls". Please define all elements for this path in one config file.". It seems that Symfony is not allowing to define security config in multiple files.

Comment: That is exactly what I encountered when I tried using imports.  I think the prepend stuff might be able to fool Symfony into thinking only one file is being loaded but maybe not.